# Send Serial Keys Automatically to Customers

Tags: html, css

I have literally no coding skills. I know a little about bat, and html, and css. I hope someone can help with my question, as it seems no one has been willing to help me figure this out yet.

The Problem:

I manually send software keys these days to my own customers through secure email. But it has become tiresome, and some end users want the code right away, even at 4 am when I am sleeping.

The Question:

What do I have to do to code into my website to send the end user their serial key by email automatically? Have it automatically send the keys. All I would have to do is upload them securely somewhere for it to get it.

Maybe dropbox?

Any help would be helpful. Currently using wordpress. Would be willing to purchase any code or software if its already out there. Just having a hard time being able to locate it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After many more searches I did find the answer **finally!** I went to http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com, went to products, and found "e-store". This plugin allows you to sell everything digital. And gives you the tools you need for a good price. I decided to buy the Affiliate  and e-store plug-in.

Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 1):

I've found my solution using Woo-Commerce and this solution:

https://www.licensemanager.at/

Basically, I'll be creating my own set of serials that have checksums in them (not using the built-in generators), and then load a few hundred in there ready to be sold and issued when people make a purchase.
Through the basic API of that plugin, I can then get the user to register online and so keep track roughly of when it's been used.
All free, just takes a while to set up, specifically the validating code in my program.

It's still fairly simple and primitive, but you can work around it's limitations.

I'd love to see if having customisable user level API permissions per API user, rather than a flat 'on/off' for each of the JSON API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not wordpress expert, I write custom php applications and I have an application with the functionality that you are asking. The application has password recovery page, product key retrieval page. And user gets Text Message and email.

Wordpress is written in php, so you can use the php mail(); function to send the email to the customer.

You can store the keys and other data in a database table. And create a page from where the users can fetch the required data automatically.

Lets say that a returning customer lost his key, he will come to the site, and will fill in his subscription email or other credentials, and the php script will fetch the key from database and send it to the user email using the mail function.

Refer : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Hope this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **Wordpress** for a fast website enviroment deploy, with the **Woocommerce plugin**, to allow people to buy your software, and the **WooCommerce Software Add-on** , to provide them the licences, once the payment is done.

---

**WordPress**

> WordPress is open source software you can use to create a
>   website, blog, or app.

[Wordpress Site](https://wordpress.org/download/)

---

**Wordpress WooCommerce Plugin**

> WooCommerce is a free eCommerce plugin that allows you to sell
>   anything, beautifully. Built to integrate seamlessly with WordPress,
>   WooCommerce is the world’s favorite eCommerce solution that gives both
>   store owners and developers complete control.

[Wordpress Plugin Site](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/)

---

**WooCommerce Software Add-on**

> The WooCommerce Software Add-on gives you the ability to manage
>   license keys and activations via your store.

[Woocommerce Add.on Site](https://woocommerce.com/products/software-add-on/)

Comment: The add-on does not allow you to input keys you have or automatically email them to the customer.

Comment: Yes it does:
"To view licenses not associated to orders, or just to get an overall view you can go to WooCommerce > License Keys for a list of keys. "
...and:
"Customers purchase software like any other product, but after doing so (when the order is completed) they will receive an auto-generated license key from the system within their order-complete email."

Comment: Its an auto generated key that it sends. Meaning it generates its own key. I had installed it and tested it. But it generates keys. You cant upload a large list of keys on it at all which is what I also wanted. Instead if you were assigning one customer a key you have to manually type all their info and the key.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make your users sign up to your website. Like a registration form that allows users to register once, then upon registration, you assign a serial to their details and store them in a database. Then the script can send the serial to the user's email. PhP works pretty good for me.